# Вставка select в заголовок Angular Ui Grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Помогите разобрать этот пример:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28097758/angular-ui-grid-how-to-create-a-pre-populated-dropdown-menu-for-column-filterin

Мне нужно, чтобы в заголовке колонки был select. Делаю все как в примере, но у меня нет константы SELECT в `uiGridConstants.filter.SELECT`. Есть только такие:

```
ENDS_WITH:4

EXACT:8

GREATER_THAN:32

GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL:64

LESS_THAN:128

LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL:256

NOT_EQUAL:512

STARTS_WITH:2
```

Мой код:

```
var testOptions = [
        { value: 'type1', label: 'type1' },
        { value: 'type2', label: 'type2' },
        { value: 'type3', label: 'type3' },
        { value: 'type4', label: 'type4' },
    ];

$scope.testData = [
        { displayName: '[Acitve Directory]FIM_G-NPF', type: 'type3' },
        { displayName: '[Acitve Directory]ДБУиО документация по проекту', type: 'type2' }
    ];

$scope.gridOptions = {
        enableFiltering: true,
        enableScrollbars: false,
        enableHorizontalScrollbar: 2,
        enableVerticalScrollbar: 2,
        enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
        enableFullRowSelection: true,
        multiSelect: false,
        enableRowSelection: true,
        noUnselect: true,
        data: $scope.testData,
        columnDefs: [
            { name: 'displayName' },
            {
                field: 'type',
                filter: { selectOptions: testOptions, type: uiGridConstants.filter.SELECT }
            }
        ]
};
```

Comment: ну так добавте после декларации `type` декларацию `selectOptions: [ { value: '1', label: 'male' }, { value: '2', label: 'female' }, { value: '3', label: 'unknown'}.....`, или выложите хоть какой-то код чтобы разобраться можно было

Comment: Добавил код своего контроллера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
angular.module('exampleApp', ['ui.grid'])
  .controller('exampleCtrl', ['$scope', 'uiGridConstants',
    function($scope, uiGridConstants) {
      var testOptions = [{
          value: 'type1',
          label: 'type1'
        }, {
          value: 'type2',
          label: 'type2'
        }, {
          value: 'type3',
          label: 'type3'
        }, {
          value: 'type4',
          label: 'type4'
        }, ];
       $scope.testData = [{
          displayName: '[Acitve Directory]FIM_G-NPF',
          type: 'type3'
        }, {
          displayName: '[Acitve Directory]ДБУиО документация по проекту',
          type: 'type2'
        }];

      $scope.gridOptions = {
        enableFiltering: true,
        data: $scope.testData,
        columnDefs: [{
          name: 'displayName'
        }, {
          field: 'type',
          filter: {
            selectOptions: testOptions,
            type: uiGridConstants.filter.SELECT
          }
        }]
      };

    }
  ]);
```

```html
<link href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.js"></script>

<div ng-app="exampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="exampleCtrl">
    <h1>UI Grid Dropdown Filter Example</h1>
    <div ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Не знаю тогда, почему... Что консоль пишет?

Comment: Ничего, я в консоли вывел `uiGridConstants.filter`, там нет SELECT, но есть другие свойства, которые я написал выше.

Comment: может быть у нас разная версия ui-grid.js я в visual studio 2015 через nuGet добавил AngularUI latest stable version.

Comment: скорее всего разная, судя по [мануалу](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/103_filtering) и [ентому](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/3681) фильтр прописан в ручную.  [код 30-я строка](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/103_filtering) - привязка к колонке. на 97-й `.filter('mapGender', function()...` декларация

Comment: @endovitskiiy неправильно я сказал `ui-grid - v3.2.5 - 2016-07-01` используется в примере. Angular устаревшая, но это не должно играть особой роли. Попробуйте убрать всё кроме самого необходимого из `gridOptions`, может поможет

Comment: у меня ui-grid - v3.0.0-RC.18 - 2014-12-09

Comment: ))) RC = release condidate. Это да не офф релиз. Проапгрейде версию. (Если можете конечно)

Comment: Обязательно, теперь понятно в чем была проблема.